# Regex to match some words excluding strings with a dot

Tags: ruby, regex

What is the regex to match `"Colorado"`, `"Co"`, or `"CO"`, excluding strings that include a period such as `"Co."` or `"co."`?

This:

```
/\b(Colorado|Co|CO)\b/i
```

matches the two instances of `"CO"`. How do you exclude matches that contain the dot?

This:

```
\b(?:(?!Co\.)\w)+\b
```

ignores `"Co."`, but I can't figure out how to combine that with the keywords allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may add a negative  lookahead after `Co`:

```
/\b(Colorado|Co(?!\.))\b/i
               ^^^^^^
```

See the [Rubular demo](http://%5Cb(Colorado%7CCo(?!%5C.))%5Cb)

Note I omitted `co` alternative since you are using a case insensitive `i` modifier that makes `Co` equal to `co`.

Another way is to add the negative lookahead before the group after the first `\b`:

```
/\b(?!Co\.)(Colorado|Co)\b/i
   ^^^^^^^^
```

See [another Rubular demo](http://rubular.com/r/69D6xHm53n).

Here, `\b` asserts the position at the word boundary, then `(?!Co\.)` fails the match if `Co.` is the text immediately to the right of the current location, and `(Colorado|Co)\b` matches a whole word `Colorado` or `Co`.

Note you may further shorten the pattern if you write it manually, like

```
/\b(?!Co\.)Co(?:lorado)?\b/i
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Simple and works great.